# Cannot set wifi card to use non-HT IBSS modes using iw

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, embedded, openwrt

I have two embedded systems that will be communicating with each other using Doodle Labs NM-915-1F wifi transceivers. One system is an [Axiomtek PICO831](http://www.axiomtek.com/Download/Spec/pico831.pdf) running Arch Linux 4.10.9-1-ARCH, and the other is a [Gateworks Ventana GW5220](http://www.gateworks.com/imx6-single-board-computers-gateworks-ventana-family/item/ventana-gw5220-single-board-computer) running a custom OpenWrt build, Gateworks 16.02@9c4230b (based on Designated Driver r48868). I am having difficulty getting the GW5220 to set the NM-915-1F to use any bandwidth other than the default 20MHz in IBSS mode. Specifically, I want to get both devices communicating at 5MHz.

Here is the output on both devices after running `iw dev wlan0 ibss join KE8BKT 2442 5MHz`:

GW5220

```
phy#0
Interface wlan0
    ifindex 10
    wdev 0x1
    addr 00:30:1a:4e:0e:68
    ssid KE8BKT
    type IBSS
    channel 7 (2442 MHz), width: unknown, center1: 2442 MHz
    txpower 24.00 dBm
```

PICO831

```
phy#0
Interface wls2
    ifindex 3
    wdev 0x1
    addr 00:30:1a:4e:0e:69
    ssid KE8BKT
    type IBSS
    channel 7 (2442 MHz), width: 5 MHz, center1: 2442 MHz
    txpower 14.00 dBm
```

In this state neither device can communicate with the other. They do not detect each other when setting either device to IBSS mode at 5MHz and scanning with the other. However if I allow them to use the default bandwidth they can communicate just fine (meaning I can get them to ping each other), `iw dev wlan0 ibss join KE8BKT 2442`:

GW5220

```
phy#0
Interface wlan0
    ifindex 10
    wdev 0x1
    addr 00:30:1a:4e:0e:68
    ssid KE8BKT
    type IBSS
    channel 7 (2442 MHz), width: 20 MHz (no HT), center1: 2442 MHz
    txpower 30.00 dBm
```

PICO831

```
phy#0
Interface wls2
    ifindex 3
    wdev 0x1
    addr 00:30:1a:4e:0e:69
    ssid KE8BKT
    type IBSS
    channel 7 (2442 MHz), width: 20 MHz (no HT), center1: 2442 MHz
    txpower 30.00 dBm
```

I am almost certain that the PICO831 is correctly transmitting with a 5MHz bandwidth because I've directly observed it using an STL-SDR. I don't have access to one at the moment to check the GW5220 however, but I am almost certain it is the device at fault here. I have the full `lspci`, `iw phy`, and `dmesg` outputs from both devices on pastebin below. Of note is that the `iw phy` output for the PICO831 is much more detailed than the output for the GW5220.

GW5220:

[lspci](https://pastebin.com/fvdF0Wp8)

[iw phy](https://pastebin.com/exYs5NM4)

[dmesg](https://pastebin.com/jUcpdu7b) (note that this is direct output from `dmesg` and has the ANSI color codes attached, reading it with `less -r` makes it more legible)

PICO831:

[lspci](https://pastebin.com/rhtvEh06)

[iw phy](https://pastebin.com/LX7PZHGA)

[dmesg](https://pastebin.com/MFVj0TqK)

I appreciate any help with this. I couldn't find any relevant information in the `iw` documentation or by searching the web. Hopefully this is the right place to ask.

Comment: First guess is that the 5Mhz bandwidth is not supported on GW5220 hardware and/or driver; the generic "HT Capability overrides/supported channel width" may not include the 5Mhz. I'm actually amazed it works on the PICO831. I don't see any way to verify this other than reading the source code of the driver of the GW5220.

Comment: The GW5220 drivers should be from ath9k, which in turn is from the backports project. According to the [Gateworks OpenWrt page](http://trac.gateworks.com/wiki/OpenWrt/building#OpenWrtBSPBranches), their build uses backports-20151218. It also uses the 4.4.0 kernel, whereas the PICO831 is using the 4.10.9 kernel. I wonder if the version of ath9k on the PICO831 is newer than the one on the GW5220, and that is why it can use 5MHz.

Comment: I have no idea, the obvious way to find out is to compare the source. And ath9k isn't ath9k, still one HW may be capable of 5 MHz bands, while the other HW may not.

Comment: What do you mean by “ath9k isn’t ath9k”? And do you mean to say that the embedded computers themselves may not be capable of 5 MHz bandwidths, not the transceivers? Because are using the same transceiver, the NM-915-1F. It seems strange to me that the capabilities of the WiFi transceivers would be limited by the SBC’s hardware.

Comment: Just because the driver is the same, the details of the WLAN HW needn't be the same. However, if both use the same WLAN HW (which wasn't clear to me from your question), then yes, it must be other differences, like the driver/kernel version. Is anything stopping you from cross-compiling 4.10.9 for the GW5220, and trying with that?

Comment: Gateworks has some drivers they include for some of the specialized functions of the GW5220 (input voltage detection, temperature sensors, CAN bus, etc). I’m not sure if those would compile with the 4.10.9 kernel. However there is a bigger obstacle: I figured out how to cross-compile the provided Gateworks OpenWrt distro a week ago, so it’s pretty safe to say I wouldn’t know how to modify it to use the 4.10.9 kernel. If that is indeed the next step then I guess I will need to learn.